# How to maximize the number of teams of 3 players

Tags: c, algorithm

There are N students in a class, and Teacher wants to divide these students into some groups. Teacher says that groups consisting of two or less students is not allowed, so Teacher wants to us to have as many groups consisting of three or more students as possible.

Divide the students so that the number of groups consisting of three or more students is maximized.

I have written the code up to the following, but it is not giving the correct result for some test cases. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n%3 == 0){
        printf("%d", n/3);
    }
    else if(n%4 == 0 && n/4 == n/3){
        printf("%d", n/4);
    }
    else if((n-4)%3 == 0){
        printf("%d", ((n - 4)/3)+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a failing example, the wrong output and the expected one.

Comment: Please add what you have found out by debugging yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", n/3);
}
```

**Let me know it outs right answer**
**I believe this is the most simple one**

Comment: I suggest to add some explanation why this simple calculation is sufficient to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: (N  : G ) (3:1) (4:1) (5:1) |
(6:2) (7:2) (8:2) |
(9:3) (10:3) (11:3)

Comment: Hi, @MohammadRajinRashidChowdhur, How could you group 8 students?
4 + 4 OR 3 + 5 is the only answer, 3+3+2 is not able. isn't it?

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. Turns out I overcomplicated the problem in my head

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing anything for (e.g.) n = 20.